# How to force remounting on React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say I have a view component that has a conditional render:

```
render(){
    if (this.state.employed) {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyInput ref="job-title" name="job-title" />
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyInput ref="unemployment-reason" name="unemployment-reason" />
                <MyInput ref="unemployment-duration" name="unemployment-duration" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

MyInput looks something like this:

```
class MyInput extends React.Component {

    ...

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input name={this.props.name} 
                    ref="input" 
                    type="text" 
                    value={this.props.value || null}
                    onBlur={this.handleBlur.bind(this)}
                    onChange={this.handleTyping.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Lets say `employed` is true. Whenever I switch it to false and the other view renders, only `unemployment-duration` is re-initialized. Also `unemployment-reason` gets prefilled with the value from `job-title` (if a value was given before the condition changed).

If I change the markup in the second rendering routine to something like this:

```
render(){
    if (this.state.employed) {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyInput ref="job-title" name="job-title" />
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>Diff me!</span>
                <MyInput ref="unemployment-reason" name="unemployment-reason" />
                <MyInput ref="unemployment-duration" name="unemployment-duration" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It seems like everything works fine. Looks like React just fails to diff 'job-title' and 'unemployment-reason'.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What's the `data-reactid` on each of the `MyInput` (or `input`, as seen in DOM) elements on before and after the `employed` switch?

Comment: @Chris I failed to specify that the MyInput-component renders the input wrapped in a `<div>`. The `data-reactid` attributes seems to be different on both the wrapping div and the input field. `job-title` input gets id `data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.1.0.1"`, while `unemployment-reason` input gets id `data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.1.2.1"`

Comment: and what about `unemployment-duration`?

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I spoke too soon. In the first example (without the "diff me" span) the `reactid` attributes are identical on `job-title` and `unemployment-reason`, while in the second example (with the diff span) they're different.

Comment: @Chris for `unemployment-duration` the `reactid` attribute is always unique.

Comment: Okay, so I think I know what's happening here. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

What's probably happening is that React thinks that only one `MyInput` (`unemployment-duration`) is added between the renders. As such, the `job-title` never gets replaced with the `unemployment-reason`, which is also why the predefined values are swapped.

When React does the diff, it will determine which components are new and which are old based on their `key` property. If no such key is provided in the code, it will generate its own.

The reason why the last code snippet you provide works is because React essentially needs to change the hierarchy of all elements under the parent `div` and I believe that would trigger a re-render of all children (which is why it works). Had you added the `span` to the bottom instead of the top, the hierarchy of the preceding elements wouldn't change, and those element's wouldn't re-render (and the problem would persist).

Here's what the official [React documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) says:

> The situation gets more complicated when the children are shuffled around (as in search results) or if new components are added onto the front of the list (as in streams). In these cases where the identity and state of each child must be maintained across render passes, you can uniquely identify each child by assigning it a key.
>
> When React reconciles the keyed children, it will ensure that any child with key will be reordered (instead of clobbered) or destroyed (instead of reused).

You should be able to fix this by providing a unique `key` element yourself to either the parent `div` or to all `MyInput` elements.

For example:

```
render(){
    if (this.state.employed) {
        return (
            <div key="employed">
                <MyInput ref="job-title" name="job-title" />
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div key="notEmployed">
                <MyInput ref="unemployment-reason" name="unemployment-reason" />
                <MyInput ref="unemployment-duration" name="unemployment-duration" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

OR

```
render(){
    if (this.state.employed) {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyInput key="title" ref="job-title" name="job-title" />
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyInput key="reason" ref="unemployment-reason" name="unemployment-reason" />
                <MyInput key="duration" ref="unemployment-duration" name="unemployment-duration" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, when React does the diff, it will see that the `divs` are different and will re-render it including all of its' children (1st example). In the 2nd example, the diff will be a success on `job-title` and `unemployment-reason` since they now have different keys.

You can of course use any keys you want, as long as they are unique.

---

**Update August 2017**

For a better insight into how keys work in React, I strongly recommend reading my answer to [Understanding unique keys in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/2030321).

---

**Update November 2017**

This update should've been posted a while ago, but using string literals in `ref` is now deprecated. For example `ref="job-title"` should now instead be `ref={(el) => this.jobTitleRef = el}` (for example). See my answer to [Deprecation warning using this.refs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873736/2030321) for more info.

Comment: `it will determine which components are new and which are old based on their key property.` - that was... key... to my understanding

Comment: Thank you a lot ! 
I had also figured out that all the children components from a map were successfully re-rendered and I couldn't understood why.

Comment: a nice hint is to use an state variable (which changes, like an id for eg.) as the key for the div!

Answer (score 392):

Change the key of the component.

```
<Component key="1" />
```

```
<Component key="2" />
```

Component will be unmounted and a new instance of Component will be mounted since the key has changed.

Documented on [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key):

> When a key changes, React will create a new component instance rather than update the current one. Keys are usually used for dynamic lists but are also useful here.

Comment: @Alex.P. Nice! CSS animations can be tricky sometimes. I'd be interested to see an example.

Comment: React documentation describing this technique: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key

Comment: Thank you.  I am so grateful for this.  I tried feeding random numbers to undeclared props like "randomNumber" but the only prop that worked was key.

Comment: Had to use that to fix Gitgraph node, it seems to be caching props at init, making it impossible to prepare an array of graph, and make a carousel.

Comment: Does anyone know if this will still work if the key is on a parent div component? For example, if I have a div component with a key, then a react component as a child, will it always remount the child if the key changes on the parent div?

Comment: @wayofthefuture I don't know for sure, but my guess would be yes. You could test by adding a console log to componentDidMount.

Comment: what happens to the old 'instance' of `Component` when using this solution? is it stored in memory, destroyed or ?

Comment: @benwl the cleanup lifecycle methods/hooks will run and as long as you don't have memory leaks it'll be garbage collected.

Comment: wow all these year I didnt know real use of keys.

Answer (score 6):

Use `setState` in your view to change `employed` property of state. This is example of React render engine.

```
 someFunctionWhichChangeParamEmployed(isEmployed) {
      this.setState({
          employed: isEmployed
      });
 }

 getInitialState() {
      return {
          employed: true
      }
 },

 render(){
    if (this.state.employed) {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyInput ref="job-title" name="job-title" />
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>Diff me!</span>
                <MyInput ref="unemployment-reason" name="unemployment-reason" />
                <MyInput ref="unemployment-duration" name="unemployment-duration" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already doing this. The 'employed' variable is part of the view components state, and it is changed through it's setState function. Sorry for not explaining that.

Comment: 'employed' variable should be property of React state. It is not obvious in your code example.

Comment: how do you change this.state.employed? Show the code, please. Are you sure that you use setState in proper place in your code?

Comment: The view component is a bit more complex than my example shows. In addition to the MyInput-components, it also renderes a radiobutton group which controls the value of 'employed' with a onChange handler. In the onChange handler, I set the view component's state accordingly. The view re-renders fine when the value of the radiobutton group changes, but React thinks the first MyInput-component is the same as before 'employed' changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on Crud for my app. This is how I did it Got Reactstrap as my dependency.

```
import React, { useState, setState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import firebase from 'firebase';
// import { LifeCrud } from '../CRUD/Crud';
import { Row, Card, Col, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import InsuranceActionInput from '../CRUD/InsuranceActionInput';

const LifeActionCreate = () => {
  let [newLifeActionLabel, setNewLifeActionLabel] = React.useState();

  const onCreate = e => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    db.collection('actions').add({
      label: newLifeActionLabel
    });
    alert('New Life Insurance Added');
    setNewLifeActionLabel('');
  };

  return (
    <Card style={{ padding: '15px' }}>
      <form onSubmit={onCreate}>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          value={newLifeActionLabel}
          onChange={e => {
            setNewLifeActionLabel(e.target.value);
          }}
          placeholder={'Name'}
        />

        <Button onClick={onCreate}>Create</Button>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Some React Hooks in there

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to review [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Add some explanation to how you solved the question beyond just posting the code.