# How can I ensure that React creates a new instance of a component, even if the component tree has not changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React updates its component tree based on the names of the elements in that tree.

For example:

```
<div>
  <MyComponent/>
</div>
```

And:

```
<div>
  <MyComponent enabled/>
</div>
```

...results in React using the same `<MyComponent>` instance (because the component **name** did not change). This is very useful because it ensures that internal state within the component instance persists.

See [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) for more details.

My question: *"Is there a way to force a new instance to be created in certain circumstances?"*

So rather than using the same `MyComponent` instance, I would like a new one to be instantiated if (let's say) `prop 'x'` has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force remounting on React components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792275/how-to-force-remounting-on-react-components)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untested, but I think you could trick React and add the prop as a `key` on the component.

```
<div>
  <MyComponent enabled key={enabled.toString()} />
</div>
```

Since you're familiar with the reconciliation docs, I imagine you know what keys do already ;)

Comment: Wow. Missed the obvious solution. Thanks

Comment: Tested this and it works correctly. Great simple solution, and easy to overlook!