# Office ui fabric clear textfield

Tags: reactjs, typescript, textfield, office-ui-fabric

My problem is I want to clear a masked text field from Office UI Fabric with a button. Has anybody a plan how to do this?

I tried to set the value with a state but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears [`MaskedTextField`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/TextField/MaskedTextField/MaskedTextField.tsx) does nor support it directly, at least neither `value` property not `setValue` function not cause the component to re-render.

But the technique with remounting of components (see for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792275/how-to-force-remounting-on-react-components?noredirect=1&lq=1)) comes to the rescue here. 
To reset a value, the new instance of  `MaskedTextField` component is instantiated and mounted, for that matter the following component is introduced:

```
class MaskedTextFieldWrapper extends React.Component<any, any> {
  private textFieldRef: React.RefObject<MaskedTextField>;

  public generateKey(prefix:string): string {
    return `${ prefix }_${ new Date().getTime() }`;
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    if(this.props.resetValue){
      return <MaskedTextField key={ this.generateKey("textfield")} value='' ref={this.textFieldRef} {...this.props} />;  
    }
    return <MaskedTextField ref={this.textFieldRef} {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

Now the value of MaskedTextField could be reset like this:

```
class TextFieldExample extends React.Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      resetValue: false
    };
}


  public handleClick():any {
    this.setState({resetValue: true});
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div>
        <MaskedTextFieldWrapper resetValue={this.state.resetValue}  label="With number mask" mask='9999' />
        <PrimaryButton onClick={this.handleClick}>Clear</PrimaryButton>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/km4v2p72z7)