# How to place a js inside a swiper with appendTo()?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm trying to insert an echart inside a swiper (`swipeR`) on the `shiny`.

The swiper is on the server for the following reason: it's inside a `shinyWidgets::dropdown()` and I need to perform some calculations in the divs.

I tried to access the first slider with this code:

```
var putAPlot = document.getElementById('carouselSwotContainer1').swiper.snapGrid[0];
$('<div id=\"chartid1\" style=\"height: 410px;\"></div>').appendTo(putAPlot);
```

And then I inserted the JavaScript:

```
  var chart1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chartid1'));
              
              function updateChart(value1) {
                option = {
                    series: [{
                        type: 'gauge',
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        splitNumber: 10,
                        data: [{
                            value: value1,
                            name: 'Opportunities',
                            itemStyle: {
                                color: '#dd4b50'
                            },
                            pointer: {
                                length: '100%',
                                itemStyle: {
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    borderColor: '#020202'
                                }
                            },
                            title: {
                                offsetCenter: ['0', '20%']
                            },
                            detail: {
                                offsetCenter: ['0', '36%'],
                                backgroundColor: '#dd4b50',
                                color: '#f2f2f2',
                                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                borderColor: '#020202',
                                borderRadius: 5,
                                width: 32,
                                height: 20
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                };

                chart1.setOption(option);
            }
            
            // Função para obter o valor do slider e atualizar o gráfico
            function updateSlider() {
                let value1 = Number($('#slider2').val());
                updateChart(value1);
            }
            
            // Chama a função updateSlider para inicializar o gráfico com o valor inicial do slider
            updateSlider();
            
            // Adiciona um evento 'input' ao slider para atualizar o gráfico quando o valor do slider mudar
            $('#slider2').on('change', function() {
              updateSlider();
            });
```

I also tried using

```
slides[0];
```

but it didn't work.

In other words, I need to put an echarts inside swiperR (firts or other slider). I need an additional edition, which is why I didn't use the `echarts4r` package.

Complete code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  HTML(
    "<head>
      <script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js'></script>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.0/echarts.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    
    <input id='slider2' type='number' value='50'>"
  ),
  
  shinyWidgets::dropdown(
    
    inputId = "dropButton",
    width = 600,
    
    div(
      uiOutput("outSwiper")
    )
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    
    # swiper inside dropdown()
    output$outSwiper <- renderUI({
      swipeR::swipeR(
        id = "carouselSwotContainer1",
        wrapper = swipeR::swipeRwrapper(
          
          div(
            
            shinyjs::runjs(
              "var putAPlot = document.getElementById('carouselSwotContainer1').swiper.snapGrid[0];
              $('<div id=\"chartid1\" style=\"height: 410px;\"></div>').appendTo(putAPlot);
  
              var chart1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chartid1'));
              
              function updateChart(value1) {
                option = {
                    series: [{
                        type: 'gauge',
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        splitNumber: 10,
                        data: [{
                            value: value1,
                            name: 'Opportunities',
                            itemStyle: {
                                color: '#dd4b50'
                            },
                            pointer: {
                                length: '100%',
                                itemStyle: {
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    borderColor: '#020202'
                                }
                            },
                            title: {
                                offsetCenter: ['0', '20%']
                            },
                            detail: {
                                offsetCenter: ['0', '36%'],
                                backgroundColor: '#dd4b50',
                                color: '#f2f2f2',
                                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                borderColor: '#020202',
                                borderRadius: 5,
                                width: 32,
                                height: 20
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                };

                chart1.setOption(option);
            }
            
            // Função para obter o valor do slider e atualizar o gráfico
            function updateSlider() {
                let value1 = Number($('#slider2').val());
                updateChart(value1);
            }
            
            // Chama a função updateSlider para inicializar o gráfico com o valor inicial do slider
            updateSlider();
            
            // Adiciona um evento 'input' ao slider para atualizar o gráfico quando o valor do slider mudar
            $('#slider2').on('change', function() {
              updateSlider();
            });"
            )
          ),
          
          div(
            "Some text 1"
          ),
          
          div(
            "Some text 2"
          )
          
        ),
        initialSlide = 1,
        bulletsSize = NULL,
        paginationColor = "navy",
        navigationColor = "navy",
        loop = FALSE,
        height = "310px",
        width = "90%",
        effect = "cube",
        speed = 1000,
        rewind = FALSE
      )
      
    })
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT 1**

I also tried linking an id to the first slider, but to no avail. See:

```
$('#carouselSwotContainer1').on('init', function() {
    $(this).find('.swiper-wrapper').first().attr('id', 'tryFirstId');
});
          
$('<div id=\"chartid1\" style=\"height: 410px;\"></div>').appendTo('#tryFirstId');

var chart1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chartid1'));
```

Comment: I may have missed them, but I didn't see the sliders in your code (`#slider1` and `#slider2`).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent It's just that I put type='number' instead of type='range'. I just adjusted it to provide a smaller example here on the site. I also removed #slider1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. I use `dropdownButton` instead of `dropdown`, because this allows to listen to the opening event.

```r
library(shiny)
library(swipeR)
library(shinyWidgets)

js <- '
function updateChart(chart, value1) {
  var option = {
    series: [
      {
        type: "gauge",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        splitNumber: 10,
        data: [
          {
            value: value1,
            name: "Opportunities",
            itemStyle: {
              color: "#dd4b50"
            },
            pointer: {
              length: "100%",
              itemStyle: {
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#020202"
              }
            },
            title: {
              offsetCenter: ["0", "20%"]
            },
            detail: {
              offsetCenter: ["0", "36%"],
              backgroundColor: "#dd4b50",
              color: "#f2f2f2",
              fontSize: 18,
              fontFamily: "Lato",
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: "#020202",
              borderRadius: 5,
              width: 32,
              height: 20
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  chart.setOption(option);
}

// Função para obter o valor do slider e atualizar o gráfico
function updateSlider(chart) {
  let value1 = Number($("#slider2").val());
  updateChart(chart, value1);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $div = $("<div id=\\\"chartid1\\\" style=\\\"height: 410px;\\\">XXX</div>");
  var div = $div.get(0);
  var chart1;

  $("#dropButton_state").on("shown.bs.dropdown", function () {
  
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var $container = $("#toBeAppended");
      if($container.length > 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        $container.append($div);
        chart1 = echarts.init(div);
        updateSlider(chart1);
        $("#dropButton_state").off("shown.bs.dropdown");
      }
    }); 

  });
  
  // Adiciona um evento input ao slider para atualizar o gráfico quando o valor do slider mudar
  $("#slider2").on("change", function () {
    updateSlider(chart1);
  });
  
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.0/echarts.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  
  tags$input(id = "slider2", type = "number", value = "50"),

  div(id = "toBeAppende"),
  dropdownButton(
    
    inputId = "dropButton",
    width = 600,
    
    div(
      uiOutput("outSwiper")
    )
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    # swiper inside dropdown()
    output$outSwiper <- renderUI({
      swipeR(
        id = "carouselSwotContainer1",
        wrapper = swipeRwrapper(
          
          div(
            id = "toBeAppended",
            "Some text 1"
          ),
          
          div(
            "Some text 2"
          )
          
        ),
        initialSlide = 1,
        bulletsSize = NULL,
        paginationColor = "navy",
        navigationColor = "navy",
        loop = FALSE,
        height = "310px",
        width = "90%",
        effect = "cube",
        speed = 1000,
        rewind = FALSE
      )
      
    })
    

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hello again. When I translate some text inside `swipeR` with `shiny.i18n`, it goes back to the initial slide and the graphic disappears and doesn't come back. I think it's similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72711266/swiper-slider-breaks-on-language-change-in-react). Is there any way of translating the swiper content without losing the graphics? It does a sort of update and returns to the original graphic. If you need me to, I can ask you a new question. Thanks Stéphane.